# Calling function with 1 parameter @ selector.

Tags: objective-c

// Original //

I want to call this guy

```
-(void)addFavorite:(NSString *)favoriteToAdd
```

at, @selector here

```
action:@selector([addFavorite favoriteToAdd:@"string"])];
```

But I keep getting syntax error no matter which way I write it.

Can someone point out the appropriate way to call this function? When it had no parameter and was "addFavorite," it worked fine.

// Update //

I apologize for not being more specific. This is an iphone application. I have a view with a button, when the button is pressed, an NSString is grabbed and passed to addFavorite (function above). I get syntax errors when attempting to add a parameter to addFavorite.

I want to call the following addFavorite

```
-(void)addFavorite:(NSString *)favoriteToAdd
```

Something like this

```
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                              target:self
                              action:@selector([addFavorite: favoriteToAdd:@"testString"])];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
[addButton release];
```

error: Expected ':' before '[' token

Comment: I found a solution, although not very elegant. @selector, I call a function with calls addFavorite. It works. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Unfortunately that's how it will have to work. For the click button event selector you can't pass a parameter. As you intend on pulling it from somewhere that's not a problem. You'll have to call a function via the action on click & then call `addFavorite` with the string you retrieved (as mentioned in my answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[obj action:@selector(addFavorite:) withObject:@"string"]`

Edit: can't spell today :)

One of the methods for calling selector on button click:

```
[buttonObj target:self action:@selector(addFavoriteClick)]`
```

You'll then have to PULL the string in `addFavoriteClick` from where it's defined and pass it into `addFavorite:`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how this works. I want to add "favoriteToAdd," and I do not have an "obj." The @selector is an action when a button is clicked.

Comment: Do you want it to perform 'addFavorite' when you click a button?

Comment: Yes, and I want to pass addFavorite a String. I am searching for the objective-c/iphone equivalent of onClick{ addFavorite(myString); }

Comment: What kind of button are you clicking? Where is the string you want to pass to `addFavorite:` being defined?

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
          target:self
          action:@selector(addFavorite:)];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
 [addButton release];

I want to use a test string for now of @"test" but eventually I will grab the string from a title on the view. My addFavorite works. I just need to call it and pass an NSString param.

Comment: Is your problem that when you click on the button nothing happens?  You call it by pressing the button, or are you wanting to include an argument or other state with the call and that is messing you up?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                              target:self
                              action:@selector(addFavoriteClick:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
[addButton release];
```

This method will be called once the button got tapped
In the button click, pass the string which should be added as a parameter as follows

```
-(void)addFavoriteClick:(UIButton*)sender
{
   NSString *str=@"stringtobeadded";
   [self addFavorite :str];
}
```

This will help you